# Moving categories to the far right and articles on the leftover left in HTML

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I have a basic blog website and I want to move the categories on the far right and be presented under each other. And then on the rest of the space, I'd want my articles to show up.

```html
<main>
  <div class="container body-content ">
    <div class="row">
      <!--"style=width: 100%;"-->

      <div class="col-md-8" th:each="article : ${articles}" style="float: left;"> <!--"style=width: 90%;"-->
        <header>
          <h2>
            <a th:href="@{/article/{id}(id=${article.id})}" th:text="${article.name}">
            </a>
          </h2>
        </header>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4" th:each="category : ${categories}" style="float: right;">
        <header>
          <h2>
            <a th:href="@{/category/{id}(id=${category.id})}" th:text="${category.name + ' (' + #sets.size(category.articles) + ')'}">
            </a>
          </h2>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

It's not working. It' showing all my six categories in 2 rows and 3 columns in the middle of the page.

I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTJjt.jpg

I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uifyn.jpg
What am I missing?

Comment: and the problem is ? i see you are using bootstrap to split your layout into two sections. so....what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: I think (maybe?) they want a fixed width sidebar for categories on the right, and then all of the remaining space on the left to be used for articles (dynamic width).

Comment: It's not working. It' showing all my six categories in 2 rows and 3 columns in the middle of the page.

@delinear Yes, exactly

Comment: @Sibuscus Is this what you want https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbEzXx

Comment: I have this: https://imgur.com/5Q1yuLH


I want this: https://imgur.com/Au5NbH4

Comment: When your categories are added what elements are they can you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing a couple of < div tags up. Thanks everyone for the help